# Accessing knockout ViewModel properties outside

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a view model in this structure:

```
window.test = {
  viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.items = [{ name: "car", value: 0 }];

    self.onSave = function() {
      //calling some other function by sending self.items as parameters
    }
  }
}
```

This JS file is on an HTML page embedded in a parent page.

Now, I want to call self.onSave function from parent JS file. I tried test.viewModel.onSave(). But it does not work. Can you tell me how to call properties of a view model on an other JS file?

Comment: and where are you creating an instance of the view model? where is your `var whatever = new window.test.viewModel();`?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but wouldn't the viewModel be part of the Window scope with this code ? If OP wants it to be part of the "test" namespace, shouldn't he use `var viewModel = function(){...}` ?

Comment: If you can access the DOM you can use ko.dataFor(DOM element) to get the view model. Then you can call onSafe

Comment: if i am creating new window.test.viewModel(), it is creating default values of the view model observable's. i want to get current values of the veiwmodel observable's.